# My PhpMyAdmin will not show relation view with InnoDB

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, foreign-keys

I am trying to insert a foreign key to one of the tables, but PhpMyAdmin will not show **relation view** in a particular database.
I have switched all the tables to InnoDB, but still no luck.
Strangely, I have other databases in phpMyAdmin that display the relation view.

I am using MAMP. PMA is 4.2.10.

Can anyone please help with this?

Comment: Do you have a columns within your tables that are indexed? I believe if nothing is indexed at all you wont see this option.

Comment: Yes, I have all of them indexed. I really can't see why it won't work ...

Comment: phpMyAdmin 4.2.10 is outdated.

Comment: Thanks, I will update it and see how ti goes... :)

Comment: I have a new issue, trying to update. It seems as if if I try to update, I cannot go to the phpMyAdmin at all - I found that it was `add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;`
[Link to solution](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/186003/phpmyadmin-blank-page-after-login-using-nginx-php-fpm)